# How to fit Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a series of (x1,y1) points how to get back a series of (x2,y2) points that are on a Gaussian curve that has been fit to the data.

Comment: More details would do no harm, but on this information either non-linear least squares or fitting a quadratic to log y as a function of x.

Comment: Question is unclear. What's your dataset ? what's your statistical model ?

Comment: Try https://www.mycurvefit.com - select Gaussian under Non-linear.  It's a free online tool (well free for data sets < 20 points)

Answer (score 0):

what about something like (in R):

```
# generate 100 values from a guassian distribution with mean=5, sd=2
initial <- rnorm(100, 5, 2)

# estimate parameters of the guassian distribution
fitted_curve_params <- c(mean(initial), sd(initial))

# generate 100 values from those parameter estimates
generated_data <- rnorm(100, fitted_curve_params[1], fitted_curve_params[2])
```